# Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement during installation

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2

during installation of MSSQL2008 R2 on windows server 2008 R2 on a VMM machine i get this Error ,Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement during installation

how do i fix this please...?

Comment: Check errors on your disk or SAN.

Comment: Did you check the error logs? Just posting part of an error message out of context doesn't help. Also, if you google for this message you'll see various posts (and SO questions) about it - eg [check this one](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29793/could-not-continue-scan-with-nolock-due-to-data-movement-sql-server-2008-r2). It has to do with problems in an already existing database, NOT installation of a new server. If you have problems with a clean installation, the VM software or hardware may have issues

Comment: We need the context.

Comment: In any case, this type of question is suitable for http://dba.stackexchange.com . DBAs are *much* more likely to encounter and solve such issues. Make sure you mention the VM software and version you use. I'd also consider installing fresher editions of the VM, SQL Server, OS - the 2K8R2 editions are two versions behind the current ones - unpatched editions are [already](https://support.microsoft.com/en-US/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=sql%20server&Filter=FilterNO) out of mainstream support

Comment: Hi guys here are the logs  below please click on links

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_o-zHrXSTScUi00UkhVWElmWnM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

resolving issue is to install sql on different drives like C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ --Base Install D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MyInstance --Instance Binaries D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MyInstance\MSSQL\DATA --Data Files E:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MyInstance\MSSQL\LOGS --Log Files